# java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014521: No message listener of type org.quartz.Job found in resource adapter wmq.jmsra

Tags: java, jboss7.x

Recently we are migrating ejb/MDB application from Jboss 5 to Jboss 7 but getting the following exception while deploying the ear and `wmq.jmsra.rar`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014521: No message listener of type org.quartz.Job found in resource adapter wmq.jmsra
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBUtilities.createActivationSpecs(EJBUtilities.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.createComponent(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentCreateService.start(BasicComponentCreateService.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.start(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:74)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
```